# Notification.alert not working cordova version 4+

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, plugins

I'm trying to use the notification.alert but is not working.
Using as a basis this link: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_notification_notification.md.html

My cordova version 4.2

Message of error:

`TypeError: Cannot call method 'alert' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You want `navigator.notification.alert()` vs `notification.alert()`